# Result from Stored proc different to SSMS Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have the identical code in a stored proc and in a query window, but I get different results. The only difference is that the SP is selecting into a temp table and then selecting from the temp table and that it is running in an SP.

The SP has no parameters - so its not parameter sniffing, The SP has ANSI_NULLS ON.

RecId and invoiceOrderRecId are bigints, brand is nvarchar(10)

```
  SELECT 
      ZIOH.Brand, 
      Count(RecId) as NumDispatched
  FROM 
      ZFSINVOICEORDERHISTORY ZIOH
  WHERE 
      ZIOH.DISPATCHDATETIME  >=  CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)
      AND 
      ZIOH.DISPATCHDATETIME < DATEADD(DD, 1, CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE))
      AND 
      ZIOH.INVOICEORDERRECID NOT IN 
                              (SELECT 
                                   RecId 
                               FROM
                                   ZFSINVOICEORDER ZIO
                               WHERE
                                   ZIO.PARTITION = ZIOH.PARTITION)
   GROUP BY ZIOH.Brand
   ORDER BY ZIOH.Brand
```

**Results from Query Window**

```
╔═══════╦═══════════════╗
║ Brand ║ NumDispatched ║
╠═══════╬═══════════════╣
║ CCO   ║             1 ║
║ CVDUK ║            13 ║
║ FLX   ║            12 ║
║ MSFR  ║            74 ║
║ MSGR  ║             1 ║
║ MSUK  ║           211 ║
║ PIAFR ║            25 ║
║ PIAUK ║           129 ║
╚═══════╩═══════════════╝
```

**Result From SP**

```
╔═══════╦═══════════════╗
║ Brand ║ NumDispatched ║
╠═══════╬═══════════════╣
║ CCO   ║             1 ║
║ CVDUK ║             7 ║
║ FLX   ║            12 ║
║ MSFR  ║            53 ║
║ MSUK  ║           147 ║
║ PIAFR ║            21 ║
║ PIAUK ║           121 ║
╚═══════╩═══════════════╝
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)` with test date `'2016-04-21'`?

Comment: I get the same result. It was the first thing I tried.

Comment: Where are you executing the SP? Is the database context the same? Is the same user running both?

Comment: Yes I have run the SP in a query window using the same user

Comment: What happens if totally remove WHERE clause?

Comment: Have you tried your query with `SET ANSI_NULLS ON` and `OFF`?

Comment: @RuslanK. Removing the where clause - gives me the same result in the SP and Query window.

Comment: @gofr1 - setting SET ANSI_NULLS ON/OFF makes no difference to results in SP or the Query window

Comment: Pls add @@servername, db_name() to the select list both in the SP and in the SSMS query, to make sure you're hitting the same data. Also, prefix the tables with the schema (the same reason).

Comment: @dean - no still getting different results with the prefixes - tables are only in the same database on the same server anyway

Comment: Got it! there was an uncommitted transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your help, sorry to have wasted your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Uncommitted transaction was causing the difference in results - well that's a morning lost.